# Get full text of search request from Spotlight?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, spotlight, corespotlight

Since iOS9, it's possible to make Spotlight to show some items from own Application in search results. When user taps on result - App opens with some action handler.

**My question:** is it possible somehow to get the full text of user's search request in application?

**Example:** 
My application indexes item 'banana' using CoreSpotlight API.
User searches: "*banana pie*".
Spotlight shows result from my App, actually, item "*banana*".
I would like to get string "*banana pie*".

I have already tried to find it myself on developer.apple.com, looked through CoreSpotlight documentation, but didn't find anything that completely answers my question.

Comment: the Spotlight search works just the opposite, you can create a _searchable item_ (or more) only which you can pass to the API for indexing, but the API does not give you any access to the Spotlight search's engine or its own interface – as it is not your concern what the user actually typed for privacy reason; your concern is only to manage the restoration procedure in your app if your item was hit.

Comment: I agree with @holex. Well said. Additionally, I think it's worth pointing out you can use keywords with items. See here : https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreSpotlight/Reference/CSSearchableItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CSSearchableItem but Apple strictly conveys not to duplicate results. Because there are so many ways to aggregate search results now (safari, rich results, web mark up, etc) I'm assuming Apple wants to maintain their simplistic brand. So don't overwhelm your users with results they don't want. Let your native app handle that

Comment: thank you very much! I think you can formalize your comments as answers.