# Spotlight search in my remote database: is it possible and how is it possible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, spotlight, corespotlight

I have a remote server with database, and **I'd like to be able to search data from this database with iOS Spotlight search. Is it possible? If yes, how is it possible?**
Note: data in database updates frequently, and all search results must be up-to-dated.

I know about new abilities, that Apple gave to developers since iOS 9 is out:

1) CoreSpotlight and NSUserActivity could be a solution, but there are over 10 000 items in database, so it's quite difficult to register such amount of search items in spotlight, and then update them each second.

2) Web markup - of course, I can generate a website with all items of database, but search result won't be up-to-dated then, because Apple Bot will not index my website each second.
Please, correct me, if I'm wrong here.

As another solution, I decided to get search request from Spotlight and perform search in my database myself, but AFAIK it's impossible ([Get full text of search request from Spotlight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31783369/get-full-text-of-search-request-from-spotlight)).

I looked through Apple Developer website, carefully read documentation and didn't find anything, that can help me with my task.

Comment: What's your actual question? It seems you've covered all of the possibilities.

Comment: @rmaddy: it's in title and in description in the first paragraph. Other text just shows, that I tried to answer my question myself before asking it here.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, just like being able to search local data. No real difference.

Comment: @shahan Did you get any solution to this?

Comment: @shahan ,Rushi Do got any solution or any idea regrading this ?

Comment: @rushi, pavan-more, not really. There is no solution for current iOS 9. And rmaddy is wrong here, he suggests to store all the big data on the mobile device to "just like being able to search local data".